# Cordova File Plugin Error Code 3 (Abort_Error) on newer iOS Devices

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, cordova, filesystems

I am working on a Cordova Project, but got a bug with the filesystem-plugin. I can read and write just fine in the iPhone 5S Simulator (Json and jpegs). But on my iPhone 6 Device and the iPhone 6S Simulator the fileSystem.getFile() function always gives me the Error Code 3 when getting a new jpg File. Json somehow works fine. Any ideas?

```
self.savePicture = function (fileURI, callback) {
    if(self.canSave) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(self.dataDirectory, function(fileSystem) {
            var d = new Date().getTime();
            var folder = "pictures/";
            var filename = "pic_"+d + ".jpg";
            fileSystem.getFile(folder+filename, { create: true }, function(file) {
                file.createWriter(function(writer) {
                    writer.write(self.b64toBlob(fileURI, 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'));
                    app.log('saving ' +  filename + ' successful', 'data');
                    callback(filename);
                }, function() {
                    app.log('saving ' + filename + ' failed', 'data');
                });
            }, function() {
                app.log('getting File failed','data');
            });
        }, function() {
            app.log('resolvingLocalFileSystem failed','data');
        });
    }else{
        app.log('device cant save!', 'data');
    }
    callback('');
}
```

Comment: if you fixed it, post it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a solution.
I have to create the directory "pictures/" first and then the file. It works now on all devices.
But i can't explain, why the code above would work on some devices..

```
self.savePicture = function (fileURI, callback) {
    if(self.canSave) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(self.dataDirectory, function(fileSystem) {
            var d = new Date().getTime();
            var folder = "pictures/";
            var filename = "pic_"+d + ".jpg";
            fileSystem.getDirectory(folder, { create: true }, function(dir) {
                dir.getFile(filename, { create: true }, function(file) {
                    file.createWriter(function(writer) {
                        writer.write(self.b64toBlob(fileURI, 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'));
                        app.log('saving ' +  filename + ' successful', 'data');
                        callback(filename);
                    }, function() {
                        app.log('saving ' + filename + ' failed', 'data');
                    });
                }, function() {
                    app.log('getting File failed','data');
                });
            }, function(){
                app.log('getting Directory failed','data');
            });
        }, function() {
            app.log('resolvingLocalFileSystem failed','data');
        });
    }else{
        app.log('device cant save!', 'data');
    }
    callback('');
}
```